# How to make an image show properly on my website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Working on an ASP.NET Project and my current theme is a Restaurant. My question is I have made a Scaffolded item in order to create "MealsController" and my buttons (Edit, Create, Details, Delete) are working fine.

However, I'm currently stuck on how to display an image for a particular meal in "Details" tab.

My MealsController Details Method:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var meal = await _context.Meals
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.MealID == id);
        if (meal == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(meal);
    }
```

And my Views/Meals/Details.cshtml:

```
@model RestaurantModule7.Models.Meal

@{
ViewData["Title"] = "Details";
}

<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
<h4>Meal</h4>
<hr />
<dl class="row">
    <dt class = "col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
    </dt>
    <dd class = "col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Title)
    </dd>
    <dt class = "col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
    </dt>
    <dd class = "col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Price)
    </dd>
   </dl>
 </div>
  <div>
<a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.MealID">Edit</a> |
<a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Short answer: your `model` must contain that info - e.g. a pointer to an image file.  File naming conventions will likely matter (a lot).

Comment: Your model `RestaurantModule7.Models.Meal` will need to contain some piece of information that allows your view to write out the path to that file in the output HTML.  This is often just a path to the file (like /Images/Meals/TurkeyAndGravy.jpg).

Your view will include something similar to this to display the image:
`<img src="@(Model.ImageUrl)"  title='Turkey!' />`

Comment: What image do you want to show? Have you uploaded image to server while creating `Meal`? Or, you have know the specific image, and want to show it in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add images dynamically you will need to stream them from your controller action.

How to achieve this?

The way I like to solve this problem is I have a path in my `appsettings.json` which will point to a location in my wwwroot folder.

```
"FilePaths": {
    "Pictures": "wwwroot/content/img/",
},
```

Okey so now you can have a controller like so

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
     public string _imgPath;

     public MyController(IConfiguration config)
     {
         _imgPath = config["FilePaths:Pictures"];
     }

     //save file
     public async Task<IActionResult> SaveMeal(IFormFile image)
     {
          var fileName = generateName();
          var savePath = Path.Combine(_imgPath, fileName);
          using (var fileStream = new FileStream(savePath, FileMode.Create))
          {
              await image.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
          }
          //make sure to save the file name in your Meal model.
     }

     // this is what will stream the image from your controller.
     //imgName is your file name. 
     [HttpGet("{imgName}")]
     public IActionResult GetImg(string imgName)
     {
          var readPath = Path.Combine(_imgPath, imgName);
          var fileStream = FileStream(readPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

          return new FileStreamResult(fileStream , $"image/{imgName.Split('.')[1]}");
     }
}
```

So now if you have an `<img>` element you want to set the `src` to point at the `GetImg` action so essentially `/controller/action/{imgName}`

**Note:** you may need to use the `IHostingEnvironment` to point at your source code directory.

**Adding Steps**

These are the logical steps:

1. Make sure you have a variable that points to where you want to save your files
2. Upload your file (image) to the backend
3. Save the file (image) wherever your variable points to
4. Make sure you record the name of that file and store it somewhere where you can retrieve it, preferably in the database against a record to which the image relates to.

At this point we know where we save the files, we have a file that we have uploaded and we have the name of the file that we want to get. Now let's stream that file from a controller.

1. Create an img html element and make the src point to a controller action
2. Make sure that the route which is bound to the src attribute contains the name of the file.
3. Get the name of the file from the route as a value in the action
4. use this value in conjunction with our initial variable which points to where the file is saved so we can read from it.
5. once we are reading from a stream (essentially just packets of bytes) our image should be rendered.

Comment: Alright, I'm a newbie, however the way I get this is - create a folder where I store images, then I create a new controller and link it to this folder and to a particular image right? Sorry that it might feel like talking to a complete idiot, but I'm still learning :)